# Django matching URLs for simple titles

Tags: python, django, url

I'm trying to match an url in a django project. My urls are like this `http://localhost:8000/article/Google-Home-Sales-Outpace-Amazons-Alexa-For-The-First-Time-13545` and in urls.py
a have added:

```
path('article/(?P<article_title>[\w\d.\'%@+-]+)', views.article)

def article(request, article_title)):
    pass
```

but this doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `re_path` instead of `path` as shown in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/